# Overriding IIS6 wildcard maps on individual directories

Tags: iis-6, asp.net-mvc-4, wildcard-mapping

When Im publishing a MVC4 application on IIS6 i need to add the isapi.dll go get my application to work, but it enables wildcardmapping to all staticcontent to so Im trying to override wildcardsettings on a subfolder (content-folder) in my application with this guide [Overriding IIS6 wildcard maps on individual directories](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/07/overriding-iis6-wildcard-maps-on-individual-directories/) but it doesnt work out for me.

I get the error message:

```
C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts>adsutil.vbs SET /W3SVC/1/root/Content/ScriptMaps "" The path requested could not be found. ErrNumber: -2147024893 (0x80070003) Error Trying To Get the Object: W3SVC/1/root/Content
```

Does anyone knows what the error is? and what to do to fix it?

Im quite sure that my identifier is 1 on the default website

My structure on IIS is as follows

Web Sites/Default Web Site/"folder"/"application"/content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pls look at link > [This is link](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/07/overriding-iis6-wildcard-maps-on-individual-directories/) i think will help you, it is from blog, credits to Steven Anderson.